# L.geoJSON layer - it seems to add a layer for every feature rather than being a group?

Tags: leaflet

I have a topojson file that describes 2400 features. When I add it to the map and then

```
mapObj.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  console.log(layer)
}
```

I wind up with 2400 layers being printed to the console... isn't `L.geoJSON` supposed to be an extension of a `FeatureGroup` (and therefore, an extension of a `LayerGroup`)? Why is it creating so many layers?

I am using the [topojson-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson-client#feature) library in ReactJS but I don't think that should affect this. If you're unfamiliar, the `topojson.feature` method is just converting a `GeometryCollection` (something specific to a topojson file) to standard `FeatureCollection` so the variable `geojson` is a `FeatureCollection` with 2400 features. I then use `L.geoJSON` to set up the layer. My ultimate goal is to be able to remove the GeoJSON layer I am adding to the map using `mapObj.hasLayer` and `mapObj.removeLayer` but first I need to get this all in one `LayerGroup`.

`mapObj` is defined like this in a ReactJS component. It is accessed by other components by passing it through `props`.

```
var mapObj = L.map('map').setView([39.06862,-96.681679], 5);
```

Here I create the GeoJSON layer:

```
    let huc8LayerUrl = "./data/hucs/huc_8_effective_area_8per_topo.json";

    d3.json(huc8LayerUrl).then(function (json) {

      let geojson = topojson.feature(json, json["objects"]["huc_8"]);

      let huc8Layer = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            radius: 2,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            fill: "red",
            color: "#ff7800",
            weight: 0.5,
            opacity: 0.7,
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            fill: true,
          };
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.on("mouseover", function () {
            this.setStyle({
              fillOpacity: 0.05,
            });
          });
          layer.on("mouseout", function () {
            this.setStyle({
              fillOpacity: 0.2,
            });
          });
          layer.on("click", function () {
            // do stuff
          });
        },
      });
      mapObj.addLayer(huc8Layer);
    });
```

To sum up, I guess my question is:

1. How do I add a single layer for all 2400 features in the FeatureCollection?

**EDIT:**

Upon inspecting my data while debugging, I'm finding potentially unexpected behavior from Leaflet. If I put a breakpoint on `mapObj.addLayer(huc8Layer)` and stop the code, I can check the number of layers contained in the `LayerGroup` that is `huc8Layer` by using this:

```
Object.keys(huc8Layer._layers).length
```

I expect it to return 2400, one layer for each feature. It does. Then I run the `mapObj.addLayer(huc8Layer)` line of code and check how many layers are in `mapObj`:

```
Object.keys(mapObj._layers).length
```

This returns 2402 layers. There are two extra layers that seemingly get added. When I check the `instanceof` these layers, one is a `LayerGroup` (and `FeatureGroup`) and it's private `_layers` property contains 2400 features layers as I would expect. The other extra layer that got added is an `instanceof` `L.Layer` and it too has collected all 2400 feature layers in its private `_layers` property. Is this the correct behavior of Leaflet? Documentation states nothing.

Comment: @TomazicM edited, thanks.

Comment: You are out of luck here. When you add group layer to the map with the `.addLayer` method, what actually happens is that individual layers from the group are added to the map. There is no info about group layer being added to the map stored anywhere in the map object.

Comment: @TomazicM - so this is true for anybody loading a `FeatureCollection` via `L.geoJSON`? It always is added to the map as an individual layer per feature? Along with all the individual layers with a single feature, I also found it added two additional layers, one of instance type `LayerGroup` and one of instance type `Layer`. Each one had all the individuals layers listed in their private `_layers` property. Very confusing. To clarify, if I `L.geoJSON` a `FeatureCollection` that contains 22 features and add it to the map, it adds 24 layers to `mapObj._layers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet's `map.eachLayer` method simply iterates through all the individual layers that were added to the map, regardless of how these were added to the map. This means that for a group layer, group layer itself and all the member layers are listed.

Leaflet internal `map._layers` property just contains inventory of all the layers that were added to the map and are listed with the `map.eachLayer` method.

There is no built in method that would list only group layers, but not their members. This means you have to find some property that distinguishes group layers from other layers. One such property could be existence of `.getLayers()` method.

So to list only group layers, code could look like this:

```
mapObj.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  if (layer.getLayers()) console.log(layer);
}
```

Some other layer characteristic properties could be used list other types of layers.

Comment: You answered my question, so thanks. I just want to add in case anyone is looking in the future; what I did to keep track of the LayerGroup was artificially add an `id` property to it like this `huc8yLayer.id = 'myLayerID'` before adding it to the map. Then when I want to remove it, I wrote a function like this `removeLayerGroup(mapObj, layerID) {mapObj.eachLayer(function(layer) { if (layer.id == layerID) { mapObj.removeLayer(layer) } } }`.

Comment: Yes, I had that in mind to, but thought it's covered by the last statement of the answer.